# the sequence of submitting about in-app purchase app

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I want to make an app with in-app purchase.I know I should submit my app bundle and submit in-app purchase for review.But I don't know the sequence.Should I submit in-app purchase first,then I submit the app bundle for review when in-app purchase is approved?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your app if you have any in-app purchases ready to go in itunes connect (but not submitted) there will be a dialog screen that allows you to submit your in app purchases for review at the same time. Doing so will allow your app + IAP's to be approved at the same time.

Comment: can I submit in-app purchase first,then I submit the app bundle for review when in-app purchase is approved?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's actually possible; however you might as well give it a shot since no one will be able to access the IAP's until the app is released anyways.